# app that multiplies then adds then prints and wants to what's wrong with it MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

```
.data 
X: .word 3,4,5,6
Y: .word 1,2,3,4 

.text 
main: 
la $s0, X
la $s1, Y
la  $s2, X

lw $t1, ($s0) 
lw $t2, ($s1)
lw $t4, ($s2)  
mult $t1, $t2 
mflo $t3
add $t3, $t3,$t4
move $t3,$v0
li $v0,4
syscall
```

Comment: System call 4 prints strings. You probably want system call 1, which prints integers.

Comment: Recommend you to put sufficient comments in your code. It will be easier for you and others to understand what a particular part of code is doing.

Comment: As Michael says, you want syscall #1 to print the integer.  You will have to copy the integer to print into the `$a0` register before the syscall.  So, change that `move $t3, $v0` into `move $a0, $t3`, (or use `mflo $a0` instead).

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).